# Failed to restore snapshot - IndexShardRestoreFailedException file not found in elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, restore, snapshot

I am using 3 node cluster setup with the elasticsearch 1.3.1, i have 17 indices each one is having min 0.5 M (1Gi)  documents and 1.4 M (3 Gi) max. now i would like to try the snapshot and restore process in my cluster. i used the following REST calls to do the same...

**To create a repository:**

```
curl -XPUT 'http://host.name:9200/_snapshot/es_snapshot_repo' -d '{ 
    "type": "fs", 
    "settings": { 
        "location": "/data/es_snapshot_bkup_repo/es_snapshot_repo" 
    } 
}'
```

**Verified the repository:**

```
curl -XGET 'http://host.name:9200/_snapshot/es_snapshot_repo?pretty' the response is 
{ 
  "es_snapshot_repo" : { 
    "type" : "fs", 
    "settings" : { 
      "location" : "/data/es_snapshot_bkup_repo/es_snapshot_repo" 
    } 
  } 
}
```

*done the SNAPSHOT using*

```
curl -XPUT "http://host.name:9200/_snapshot/es_snapshot_repo/snap_001" -d '{
  "indices": "index_01",
  "ignore_unavailable": "true",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "wait_for_completion": true
}'
```

the response is

```
{
  "accepted": true
}
```

then I am trying to restore the snapshot by the request

```
curl -XPOST "http://host.name:9200/_snapshot/es_snapshot_repo/snap_001/_restore" -d '{
  "indices": "index_01",
  "ignore_unavailable": "true",
  "include_global_state": false,
  "rename_pattern": "index_01",
  "rename_replacement": "index_01_bk",
  "include_aliases": false
}'
```

**ISSUE:** 
As I informed I have 3 nodes. the index which I am trying to take snapshot & restore is has 6 shards and 2 replicas.

Most of the shards and its replicas are restored properly, but sometimes 1, sometimes 2 primary shards and its replicas restoring is not happen. those primary shards are in the INITIALIZING state. I allow the cluster to relocate them for more than an hour but the shards are not relocating to the correct node... I got the following exception in my node.

the restore process trying to place the shard in the other 2 nodes... but it can't possible...

```
[2014-08-27 07:10:35,492][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [node_01] processing [
  shard-failed (
    [snap_001][4], 
    node[r4UoA7vJREmQfh6lz634NA], 
    [P],
    restoring[es_snapshot_repo:snap_001],
    s[INITIALIZING]),
    reason [Failed to start shard, 
    message [IndexShardGatewayRecoveryException[[snap_001][4] failed recovery]; 
  nested: IndexShardRestoreFailedException[[snap_001][4] restore failed]; 
  nested: IndexShardRestoreFailedException[[snap_001][4] failed to restore snapshot [snap_001]]; 
  nested: IndexShardRestoreFailedException[[snap_001][4] failed to read shard snapshot file]; 
  nested: FileNotFoundException[/data/es_snapshot_bkup_repo/es_snapshot_repo/indices/index_01/4/snapshot-snap_001 (No such file or directory)]; ]]]: 
done applying updated cluster_state (version: 56391)
```

Could anyone help me to overcome this issue and please correct me if I done any mistake in these process...

FYI I am using master node to pass the curl request

Comment: This issue is fixed, i made a mistake in the fileSystem location. actually we need to point a shared file system. i gave a local location of each node. Now i changed the location to an shared mount folder [which is accessible by all nodes] and this issue is fixed, Thanks

Comment: The snapshot will be stored in a common location of all nodes. the restore operation also done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to provide a **shared file system** location which should be access by all the **elasticsearch nodes** with `read & write` permission.